# Plug-in written by C/C++ on Microsoft Edge

Tags: plugins, microsoft-edge

I'm looking for a plug-in technology that can be written by C/C++ on Microsoft Edge. Something's like Native Messaging on Google Chrome or Js-Ctypes on Mozilla. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Preview builds of Microsoft Edge support an extension model similar to that of Google Chrome, and Mozilla Firefox: [aka.ms/edge-extensions](http://aka.ms/edge-extensions). Once the Anniversary Update ships (currently planned for [August 2, 2016](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/06/29/windows-10-anniversary-update-available-august-2/)), this support will be sent out to non-Insider* users of Microsoft Edge.

If you provide additional input as to what you're seeking, this answer may change.

<sup>*You can become an Insider, and test preview builds of Windows 10 and Microsoft Edge by [joining the Windows Insider Program](http://insider.windows.com/).</sup>